# Rails routes: matching first occurrence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have url's like this:

`http://example.com/page123-some-random-words`

How can I create a rails route that gives me these two params:

`id = 123`

`misc = some-random-words`

---

This is what I've tried but doesn't work:

`get 'page(:id)-(:misc)'`

This currently gives me:

`id = 123-some-random`

`misc = words`

**Solution:**

Here's what ended up working:

`get 'page(:id)-(:misc)' => "posts#index", constraints: { :id => /[0-9]+/}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this type of route

```
get "/page/:id/:misc" => "yourcontroller#action"
```

Comment: That would change the url structure. Is there no way to match the first hyphen in routes?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints checkout 4.2 Specifying Constraints

Comment: Thanks. Found on there that the constraints can take a regex.